# Static UITableView in a UIViewController isn't visible

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I created in Storyboards a UIVIewController with a Navigation Bar and a static TableView.

When i try to open the View then i can only see the Navigation Bar but not the TableView. 
What am i missing?

This is how it look like in my Storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110668/static-table-view-inside-uiviewcontroller-xcode-5

Answer (score 0):

Check the positioning and if it's hidden. 
Is the datasource and delegate of the tableView linked with the viewController?