# XCode 5 Storyboard Tab View not showing Table Cell Text

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard, tableview

I have a Tab View Controller that has four different tabs. Each tab is a View Controller with a Table View widget. Each Table View widget on the tabs will have a set amount of rows, and each row should have unchangeable text. For some reason, the text I have in each row is not showing up in the simulator. If I put a label in it does show up. What could be causing this?

Storyboard:

[image]

What it looks like in simulator:

[image]

Comment: What is the base class of your PerformanceViewController? Are cells in table view static?

Answer (score 0):

> If I put a label in it does show up.

This gives me a hint that you use `UIViewController` as a base class for `PerformanceViewController`. Static table cells work with `UITableViewController` out-of-the-box  only. Therefore, possible solutions are:

- use `UITableViewController` as a base class
- implement table view delegates and return static cells, reference: [Static table view inside UIViewController [Xcode 5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110668/static-table-view-inside-uiviewcontroller-xcode-5)

Comment: Also make sure the tableview is actually set to have static content in IB