# Accessing parent view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview, parentviewcontroller

I have a `mainViewController` with a `container view` in it. I'm trying to access `theMainViewController` from the `container view`.

Here is my code:

```
self.theMainViewController = (theMainViewController *)self.parentViewController;

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0];
[self.theMainViewController .tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
```

This doesn't work. `self.theMainViewController` gives a `nil` value when I make an `nslog` of it. I then replaced:

```
self.parentViewController
```

to:

```
self presentingViewController
```

and it gave me the same results. How can I access the `mainViewController` from the `container view's` class?

**Update**

This is my setup: [Static table view inside UIViewController [Xcode 5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110668/static-table-view-inside-uiviewcontroller-xcode-5#answer-22415474) (I can't add images, so the image posted in that answer, is the same as my setup.)

Comment: Show how you setup the container view controller and the child view controllers.

Comment: @Jessica you may want to redefine your view controllers hierarchically. Here is great [article](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html) describing how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "prepareForSegue" in the parent view controller to pass self to the container view like so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"containerview_myIdentifier"]) {

         ContainerViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
         [vc setReferenceToParentVC:self];
    }
}
```

Where you create a synthesized property in ContainerViewController of type ParentViewController and set that property to self.

Here is what you should see in storyboard:
[image]

Comment: What type of object is `ReferenceToParentVC`?

Comment: @Jessica It should be "ParentViewController" for example, one of mine is as follows `@property (nonatomic) PagesViewController *referenceToRootViewController; ` Just be sure to declare the ParentViewController header in the head of the container view controller like this `#import "PagesViewController.h"`

Comment: Oh that's my bad, I forgot this will create a circular dependency loop. So instead declare the `pacesViewController` as `@class pacesViewController;` and then declare it regularly with `#import` in your .m

Comment: So should I do `[vc setReferenceToParentVC:self];`?

Comment: Yes. That's fine as it sets the variable `refereceToParentVC` to the instance of the `ParentViewController` that holds the container view.

Answer (score 0):

MainViewController - ContainerView

You create delegate in containerview and mainview will implement from this delegate.

You can try this:
http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2014/05/29/passing-data-between-view-controllers-ios-obj-c.aspx